# Using Dynamic Linq with late bound crm 2015 entities

Tags: linq, dynamic-linq, late-binding, dynamics-crm-2015

I want to make a simple query using Dynamic Linq against crm 2015.
The entity is *new_entity* and has a string field *new_field*. I want all the new_entity records that have *new_field != null* and are in a list of provided values.

```
List<string> possibleValues = new List<string> { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4" };

string stringQuery = ????;

var result = (from e in organizationServiceContext.CreateQuery("new_entity")
                      .Where(stringQuery)
                      select e).ToList();
```

I'm using **late bound** entities so *CreateQuery* will return an `IQueryable<Entity>` not `IQueryable<new_entity>`. How do I create the stringQuery predicate in order to filter *new_field* with the list of possible values?

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
.Where(ne => ne.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_field") == "my value")
```

Comment: I'm using the Dynamic Linq library. In this case, the `Where` method will take a string parameter to filter the results. I also need to filter the results with the list of values not just one.

Comment: The Dynamic Linq Library will not work in combination with Dynamics CRM. For CRM a custom implementation was designed based on the `QueryExpression`, but only a subset of its capabilities is supported. The `in` operator for example is not implemented. Also, the right side of an expression must always be a literal. All conditions must be contained within the Where clause, otherwise the query may not be interpreted correctly.

Comment: So you're saying that I can't use linq with crm late bound entities in a dynamic way? I can only accomplish that using `QueryExpression`? If you put that in an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I am saying you cannot use Dynamic Linq Library and similar constructs in Linq for CRM, regardless if using early bound or late bound.